# postmap: fatal: open database /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db: Permission denied

Tags: postfix, gmail

I'm configuring Postfix to use external smtp. For this, I used [this tutorial](http://carlton.oriley.net/blog/?p=31)

After following it, I found in the logs that `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db` couldn't be read. The file didn't exist. I used postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd (http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/smtpauth/smtp_auth_mailservers.html) as root, but I get:

```
postmap: fatal: open database /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db: Permission denied
```

Why do I get this?

```
OS: Fedora 14
User "postfix" exists.
```

Update:

```
sudo ls -l /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db ls:

cannot access /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db: No such file or directory

touch /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
chmod 640 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
chown postfix:root /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db

sudo ls -l /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db

-rwxr--r--. 1 postfix root 0 Feb 19 04:16 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
-rw-r-----. 1 postfix root 0 Feb 19 04:16 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db

postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

postmap: fatal: cannot remove zero-length database file /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db: Permission denied.
```

`chmod 777` gives the same error as above.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to make sure that postfix user is able to read that file. You can post the output of `$ sudo ls -l /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db` to get more help.

To create this file, you can use the command:

```
$ sudo postmap sasl_passwd
```

This will create the `.db` file.

Comment: OK, I got:

sudo ls -l /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db

ls: cannot access /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db: No such file or directory

touch /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db

chmod 640 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
chown postfix:root /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db

sudo ls -l /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
-rwxr--r--. 1 postfix root 0 Feb 19 04:16 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db

-rw-r-----. 1 postfix root 0 Feb 19 04:16 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db

postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

postmap: fatal: cannot remove zero-length database file /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db: Permission denied

chmod 777 gives the same.

Comment: So, the file does not exist. You need to create it or find the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I updated my answer. Please see it above.

Comment: This is unclear. Please, edit your question instead! Did you create the file using `touch`? This may not be appropriate.

Comment: Ok, done. Yes I used touch, how should I create it otherwise?

Comment: I updated my answer. Have another look.

Comment: Ok, but I got postmap: fatal: open database sasl_passwd.db: Permission denied.

Then, I changed the owner of the config directory of postfix to postfix and it worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This issue, at least on Ubuntu 12.04, is caused by the /etc/postfix folder not being owned by the postfix user. (as inferred above).

The error message is caused because you should not directly create the .db file yourself.  If you did, delete it.

```
postmap: fatal: cannot remove zero-length database file /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db: Permission denied.
```

The simple fix to the original issue is:

```
sudo chown postfix /etc/postfix
```

After that, you can run this

```
sudo postmap sasl_passwd
```

Where it is assumed your clear text passwords are in the file sasl_passwd

Comment: Confirmed still an issue @ 14.04

Comment: and in 16.04 lts

Answer (score 0):

Change the owner

> chown root:wheel policy_file

Answer (score 0):

For me, to fix I had to:

1st) change the owner of the config directory of postfix to postfixs. Did this by calling:

```
sudo chown -R postfix:postfix /etc/postfix
```

2nd) called postmap:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

And it worked. sasl_passwd.db was created.

3rd) reload postfix

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix start
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

Previously I had deleted the old sasl_passwd.db file and I also stopped postfix by calling `service postfix stop`.
Not sure if it makes any difference, but worth trying if you get any error.